# Symfony form checkbox label translate

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, symfony-2.2, sonata-user-bundle

I am using Sonata Admin + Sonata ORM + Sonata User for editing users. When editing a user there are several checkboxes. Each checkbox has two labels (one before the checkbox and another one after the checkbox). Both labels have the same value but only one is translated.

It looks like sonata has nothing to do with this issue because it does not have custom templates for checkboxes. Is there any way to translate both labels?[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be help you

You can add **translator** in config.yml

**Example**

```
 framework:

     translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
```

Comment: The text that is before the checkbox is translated. The solution is not relevant.